# jaxb xjc - how to generate unit test files

Tags: java, unit-testing, jaxb, xjc

One of my project https://github.com/maithilish/gotz uses JAXB and to generate classes from schema it uses XJC along with maven-jaxb2-plugin. As the generated classes are basic POJO, is it possible to generate unit test cases for generated classes either through xjc or jaxb plugin.

Comment: What would you expect in such a unit test? The generated code already has a guaranteed documented behavior.

Comment: for code coverage

Comment: Generate to a separate source directory (eg target/generated-sources) and exclude that from your coverage metrics analysis.

Comment: Excluding them is not an option. Even though generated code has guaranteed behavior, still  I need to test them to avoid any accidental code change. It is not big deal, I can write test cases, but before doing that I just want to know whether xjc or maven-jaxb2-plugin has any feature to generate test cases.

Comment: I don't think there's a feature like that. But again, it would be pointless because if there are code changes and the unit tests are auto generated, the tests would automatically change as well. Also, you'd notice code changes anyway because the client code wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of `maven-jaxb2-plugin` here.

There is no such feature in `maven-jaxb2-plugin` and, frankly, there probably will never be. I cannot really imagine, what you would like to achieve with such unit tests. XJC-generated schema-derived classes are normally dumb as stones, there's literally nothing to test there. Generating tests just "for code coverage" is not reasonable from my point of view.

However, I have one hint you may find helpful. What I do sometimes is so-called "roundtrip" tests where I take some sample XML, unmarshal it then marshal it an compare to the original XML. [JAXB2 Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics) can generate nice deep `equals` methods if you want to compare object structures instead.

Roundtrip tests make some sense if you want to make sure your schema-derived classes match your XML. But you really don't need ane unit test generation for this.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent JAXB2 plugin. I will go with Roundtrip test as it ensures any accidental changes to schema or schema-derived classes are caught early.